# How to plot graph in Pythonanywhere bash

Tags: python, bash

How to plot graph in Pythonanywhere bash console using python matplotlib without saving the graph as a file

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(100))

fig.savefig("graph.png")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean by plotting in Bash console? Do you mean running that code in am IPython or Python console you are running in the bash console? Or are you triggering running that code as a script by running `python my_script.py` in the console? Also why are you against removing the `matplotlib.use("Agg")` line and saving the plot as a file? I'm not following the need to complicate things here. Also PythonAnywhere offers Jupyter Notebooks and so why not just run a modified version of your code there? Then `plt.show()` works without saving. You can remove ...

Comment: <continued> the `matplotlib.use("Agg")` line and just put `%matplotlib inline` at the top of the cell above your code with the last line being like Sai suggest with `plt.show()`. Actually you may not even need `plt.show()` because modern Jupyter generally just displays a plot when the end of the cell is encountered and there is an active plot.

Comment: Oh wait, I see the free standard account level no longer supports Jupyter. Nevermind about that as an option. You can though use MyBinder sessions  or JupyterLite to run that code elsewhere without needing to save it as an image file. For a MyBinder-served temporary Jupyter session go to [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and press the 'launch binder' badge. Save anything useful you make back to your local system ASAP because it is a temporary virtual remote machine without persistence. To use JupyterLite go [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) & click...

Comment: <continued> For JupyterLite go to [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and press on one of the options in teal colored text in the upper right of the main page. I prefer JupyterLab but whatever should work. The demo notebook that comes up as 'intro.ipynb' when you start it will show you how to plot with an example under 'An example: visualizing data in the notebook '. Just substitute in your main three lines beginning with `fig =` and ending before the save line with the content after first two lines and before `plt.show()`.